# How to capture camera image thumbnail and full image at the same time

Tags: android, image, camera, save, capture

It looks like in camera image capture, one can only capture either thumbnail or full image but not both in one pass because

```
 public void startCamera() {
 ...
    camera.putExtra("output", imageUri); (step 1)
 ...
```

needs to be declared before

```
 ...
 startActivityForResult(camera, IMAGE_CAPTURE); (step 2)
 ...
    Bundle extras = camera.getExtras();
    mImageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
    imageView.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);
 ...
```

But once "onActivityResult" returns, the full image is already saved into imageUri and the buffer cleared. But to capture the thumbnail of an image taken, the code needs to be executed after "startActivityForResult". The problem is the image buffer is cleared once the image is saved in step 2. To capture the image thumbnail, one will need to skip saving the full image in step 1 in order to capture the thumbnail image in step 2.

I can use an alternative to save the full image, reload the full image into bitmap, scale the image into a thumbnail size and resave the image but it seems to be redundant. Any idea if I can do both in one pass?

Comment: I believe that the behaviour you noticed, is not universal. I encountered some devices that allowed access to both, did not destroy the thumbnail.

Answer (score 1):

Check out MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails, and specifically getThumbnail (near the bottom): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.html .

If that doesn't work, yes, you will have to manually re-scale and save the thumbnail yourself.